# Squares in the discriminant for non-maximal order subring of ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K \supset \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ be a finite extension for some algebraic number $\alpha$ where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integer for $K$. If we let $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. I know that if
$$D_{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\mathbb{Z}}(a_1,...,a_n) = m^2 \cdot D_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}.$$
Then $m = [\mathcal{O}_K \text{ : } \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$. Moreover, there exist some $\beta \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\beta \notin \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and $m\cdot\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.
My question is that I wonder if it is true in general that we have $$\text{span}_{\mathbb{Z}}\{a_1,...,a_n,\beta\} = \mathcal{O}_K?$$
That is, whether or not that we can extract a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$ from $\text{span}_{\mathbb{Z}}\{a_1,...,a_n,\beta\}$?

If this is always the case, why? If it is not true in general, then can someone give me an counter-example?

I have just started learning basic algebraic number theory recently. So maybe there are some gaps in my understanding on why some of the above statements hold. Thus a more elementary explanation is appreciated.